# Assign multiple attributes to radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

...hey guys, here is the view code in question...

```
<td>
  <%= f.radio_button :score, '4' %>
</td>
```

...and my model has...  attr_accessible :rating_id, :score, :student_id

As you can see I am assigning a score to the radio button. I also have a 'rating_id' attribute on this model, which  would also like to assign to this radio button. So ideally I would like something like...

```
  <%= f.radio_button :score => '4', :rating_id => '234' %>
```

...of course this doesn't work, but you get the picture. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving this by doing...

```
 <td>
   <%= f.radio_button :score, '4' %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :rating_id, :value => @competencys[index].ratings[0].id %>
   <%= @competencys[index].ratings[0].description %>
 </td>
```

The key for me was finding the syntax to set the value of a hidden field 'on the fly' rather than it being set in my controller.